# How would blood types and blood transfusions work in a setting with widely different humanoid races?

Tags: science-based, worldbuilding-process, blood

This is something I think is almost always overlooked in science fiction settings. Do different races have completely different blood types from those of say humans? Could a Klingon from Star Trek provide blood for a human who is bleeding out? I know that Vulcans have green blood, but is it still compatible with humans?
What if Spock needed a transfusion, but everyone aboard the Enterprise at the time was a human?

Humans alone have widely differing blood types, realistically would this apply to other races too? I imagine they'd have a huge amount of potential blood types, but they'd all be different from the ones available to humans.

Comment: What have you searched on your own? There have been people experimenting with blood transfusions in the past.

Comment: If Mr. Spock needs a transfusion the medics will use Vulcan blood from the blood bank. All hospitals have blood banks, military hospitals even more so. Blood types are an attribute which refers to transfusion compatibility within one species. Blood transfusions between two different species are most likely a no-no, unless medicine has progressed a very long way; but in such a case, why would they even consider using natural blood instead of the advanced artificial substitutes they have certainly developed?

Comment: Generally however the writer thinks the story needs. Mostly not lot of effort made to think it through. For example several Star Trek episodes have transfusions similar to our technology despite replicators and transporters making such things unnecessary. They have the technology needed to swap your blood with replicated healthy blood but no story has needed that...

Answer (score 3):

**It wouldn't**

It's not overlooked in science fiction.Typically, alien race are treated as completely different beings. Because they *are*. To clarify, moving blood from one human to another can fail if there's a *single* protein on the blood cells from the donor that the recipient doesn't have.

An alien race presumably has a lot more difference than a single protein on a blood cell, and when I say presumably, I mean *by definition*, there's not really a way for such a being to naturally evolve like that. It's actually common in sci-fi to have newcomers to an alien world being unable to eat any of the lifeforms there.

To answer your Spock question, Star Trek uses soft science fiction, considering that Spock is *half* Vulcan, the other half being human. Meaning that Star Trek has decreed that (somehow) Vulcans and Humans have a similar enough genetic code such that they can produce offspring. (I think Spock might not even be sterile, though my knowledge of Star Trek doesn't extend to that.) That still doesn't mean that he could accept pure human blood, though, because it depends on how the internal biology of his systems work. And, again, since Star Trek is soft sci-fi, they don't have to worry about that. Honestly, all they have to do is go to the food synthesizer and order a cup of warm half-Vulcan half-human blood.

Comment: *go to the food synthesizer and order a cup of warm half-Vulcan half-human blood* I confess that you were guaranteed my vote when I read this.  LOL.